# export/import categories

Tags: magento-1.9, database, php-5.4, sql, export

Hi guys I would like to export categories from one of my magento installations and import it into another:

version for the export is 1.9.2.1 and 1.9.2.4 for the import, so should have pretty much same database structure.

What tables do I need to export to "transfer" the categories as they are in 1.9.2.1 over to the 1.9.2.4 magento.

So, I guess what I am after is a list of the tables that I have to export from my Magento that houses the categories I require ?

**I have just attempted the following but didn't work:**

firstly took a data only dump of the tables:

[image: dumped tables]

Then I went and truncuated the following:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity_datetime`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity_int`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity_text`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity_varchar`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_product`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_product_index`;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Then using the mysql command to restore from a dump I ran my dump.

Now going into the backend manage category page it shows all funny:

[image: category page]

Comment: Refer http://www.justcode.in/2014/02/how-to-export-and-import-categories-in.html

Comment: @PrashantValanda would this also bring across the products links in the categories ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eav attribute ids mismatch. Both installations have the attributes in different order. So, caused incorrect references and so forth.